# Is destroying all Backbone.History.handler routes enough to have a router garbage collected?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am using `Backbone.SubRoute` to provide a means to create sub-routers on the fly from a master router.

As this provided me with a great way to modularise code I also want to tear down the router when the module is deactivated as there are many modules that create sub routers of their own and want to keep the application as light as possible.

As the routers routes are stored in `Backbone.history.handlers` I remove these on module deactivation.

```
/**
To give you an idea what allHandles may look like
RouterCallback instances are module initialisation objects, the router
always calls an activate method on these. The second method: deactivate,
tears it down
*/
allHandles = {
    "subModule1" : RouterCallback,
    "subModule2" : RouterCallback
};

// An example of what baseRoute may equal
baseRoute = "module1";

for (var path in allHandles) {
    var combinedPath = baseRoute + '/' + path;

    Backbone.history.handlers = _.reject(
        Backbone.history.handlers, function(value) {
            return String.prototype.search.call(value.route, combinedPath) !== -1;
        }
    );
}
```

I then retrieve an array of primary routes that contain only the `baseRoute` from `Backbone.history.handlers` and check that there are multiple routes registered, if there are, remove the first as it overrides the second.

```
var primaryHandlers = _.filter(Backbone.history.handlers, function(value) {
    return String.prototype.search.call(value.route, baseRoute) !== -1;
});

// Deactivate every loaded module in this routers context       
_.invoke(allHandles, "deactivate");

// If primary handlers has the parent routers callback as well as this
// then lets remove the first one that overrides the second.
if (primaryHandlers.length > 1) {
    Backbone.history.handlers.splice(
        Backbone.history.handlers.indexOf(primaryHandlers[0]), 1);
}
```

This works well for removing all trace of the router from the history.

Is this enough to have the router garbage collected? I am running profiles that would suggest it isn't, though running through the source for `Backbone.Router` and `Backbone.SubRoute` has not yielded anything that would suggest the router is referenced anywhere other than in the history. Any thoughts?

Comment: **There is a bug with this code** to definitively remove the route, a modification to `Backbone.History` needs to be made to add the original route string to each object. That route string needs to be checked in the `_.reject` function or you end up with quite a few false positives.